# Why don't posts show up in my categories on the frontend?

Tags: categories, taxonomy

The posts in a category don't show up in their category pages, like this one: http://www.kaerumusic.com/portfolio-category/japanese/ . On this page, ( http://www.kaerumusic.com/artists/ ) you're supposed to be able to sort the portfolios (artists) by category, but when one is clicked, they all disappear.

Is there anything that can help get me to the right direction in solving this?

Comment: Please post the code that you're having trouble with, so that people can try to help out.  I suspect it has to do with the fact that your pages are loading 12 artists, and then your category links at the top use Javascript to select from those 12 artists.  So on the front page, I get one artist when I click French, but none when I click Icelandic. You may need to explore an AJAX solution.